# Did Kant say something like “no fruit of the human tree has ever lacked for improvement”?

Tags: reference-request, kant

I need to fact-check something for a book.  The author says:

... to paraphrase Kant, “no fruit of the human tree has ever lacked for improvement.”

I can't find anything along these lines online in lists of Kant quotes.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a quote. An answer to this question will not help in a better understanding of philosophy.

Comment: I think if he said something like that, having the context around could be illimunitating.

Comment: It turns out to be a reference question. Most common version = "Out of the crooked timber of humanity, no straight thing was ever made." (see https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant). It's from a relatively minor Kant work though I believe Allen Wood quotes it in *Kant's Ethical Thought*

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! I've added a tag for reference-request to help make clear what kind of question this is.

Comment: "*a good human being surpasses all our concepts, for how can an evil tree produce good fruit*" https://books.google.com/books?id=YwFU4AEg6ZQC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=Kant+fruit+human+tree+improvement.&source=bl&ots=h6rfGQtKmF&sig=w8wOsu5NCEe3IvbTWkKfLmd8RwI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qH-DVajRNci5-AH1_oPYBg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Kant%20fruit%20human%20tree%20improvement.&f=false And I agree with Keelan, reference requests are fine only as long as long as they serve answering a philosophical question.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out to be a reference question.

Most common version = "Out of the crooked timber of humanity, no straight thing was ever made." (see https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant). It's from a relatively minor Kant work though I believe Allen Wood quotes it in *Kant's Ethical Thought*

There's also some things that reflect this sentiment in *Anthropology* and *Religion within the Bounds of mere Reason*, but the exact idea as you word it is not Kantian insofar as Kant thinks every human being has what they need to be moral -- and any inadequacy is incidental rather than endemic.